# Vue js and favorite/like button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm wondering how favorite, subscribe or like buttons work.
I don't understand something.

For exemple:

A user like a post with id `243`.

A ajax request is sent to the server with the id of the post (`243`) [here comes back end stuff, the user's favorite list is updated, including that post] and the server sends back a success response.

Now, how I suppose to deal with modifying the like button to actually display that is liked (permanently, including refresh).

How can I achieve that in Vue JS. How things get updated? I don't understand this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server sends back a successful response you can increment the number that is already there.

This initial number is something you have gotten either through a prop, directly from the server or through an initial AJAX request.

If you want to "permanently" update the amount of likes on your button you have to persist it to a database(or some other storage medium). On you server you could have a route that accepts a post id as an argument and increment that specific user post:

`/incrementlike/243`

That is where you would make a `POST` ajax request to. Most of the time in an MVC framework you would have a controller action/method mapped to this route that holds the logic to respond to this call.

If you are interested in the part that happens after you make an AJAX request to the server to increment your like on the backend side, I suggest you read up on routing or MVC structure.

Comment: I like the increment idea, but what if I need to display user that liked that particular post?

I'm trying to figure this out for Django (+ Django Rest Framework). There may be many tutorials for laravel, but yeah.

Comment: You could simply have a route like `/incrementlike` and send multiple variables. So you could send the `id` and the user that `liked` the post. This way you could track the last user that liked the post for example. A commonly used XHR library is axios. See the `POST` request example to see what I mean: https://github.com/axios/axios#example

Comment: I understand, that's helpful. I use axios too.
A problem: I don't know how to check if the user that makes the request has already liked that post. I don't think it's a good idea to loop through every like instance and search if that user is there.

Comment: This is something more off topic and you might want to open another more directed question for this. This depends on context, do you want to track every user that has liked this post for example, instead of the recent one, etc. But like I said this is not the place to discuss this further. If you want to figure out how to set this up in general you should check out the Django documentation or the Django community resources(irc, gitter, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

How you would do this is really done on a case by case basis. It really depends on a number of things, for example what your backend does to a post when it is liked.

If you would like a general 'explanation' to the process I attach it below, this is not really Vue specific, but the general idea is the same:

**Frontend side:**

- Modify the local state of you post to set the proper flag, ex. `post1.liked = true` immediately when it is clicked, before sending the request to the server.
- Make sure your GUI represent this change. ex. Base the color of the button on the property 'liked' of each post.
- If a failure response it received from the server, notify the user and allow them to 'try again' or something similar.
- When refreshing the page, make sure changes are fetched from the server, If you have done the backend part correctly, the modification of the state of the post will be correct in the data you receive from your backend (post1.liked will be true)

**Backend side**

When the request comes in, modify the state of the post the correct way and make sure that next time the post is fetched, the new state is sent.

Comment: Here's the part I don't understand, how can I fetch the data from server. I mean, I know how to get data from server, that's not what I meant. I don't know how to check if the post is already liked by the user that makes the request.

Comment: That really depends on what database you are using, but that is something that should be persised there and when you fetch the data originally, it should be 'based on the signed in user'. 

That means, you don't just fetch posts, you fetch posts FOR a user. 

If you, for example are using a relational database you would create a table/relation called user_likes and store when a userId likes a postId. Then when you fetch the posts you can join the user_likes table. 

But as stated above, persisting likes properly should really be a post in it's own based on your database.